# How to make nodejs wait for mongodb connection before continuing (calling async in blocking way)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I want my nodejs app to not continue unless it connects to mongodb.

I tried:

```
//Mongo
async function mongoConnect(mongoDB) {
    var mongoConnectionSuccessful = false;
    LOG("Connecting to mongodb at " + mongoDB + "...");
    while (!mongoConnectionSuccessful) {
        try {
            await mongoose.connect(mongoDB, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
            LOG("connected!");
            mongoConnectionSuccessful = true;
            mongoose.connection.on('error', ()=>LOG('MongoDB connection error:'));
            return;
        } catch (error) {
            LOG(error);
        }
        await utils.sleep(500);
    }
}
mongoConnect(config.mongoUrl);
```

but in order to use `await` in `mongoose.connect`, I must make `mongConnect` `async`, but I then cannot call it in a blocking way from the code because in order to call like this, I must call with `await`, but await is only permitted inside async functions.

Comment: If a function block contains an `await` then the function has to be `async`. What you need to do is `await mongoConnect` and put the code that follows after the function call, that way the that following code will "wait" for the promise to be fulfilled before executing.

Comment: Just call it inside an `async` function. Needing to be inside a function to be able to call a function is nothing new. We do it in C/C++ all the time. In Java it's even worse as you cannot even define a function outside a class. Just create an async function called `main` and call `main()` at the end of your script to start your program

Comment: @slebetman but I did exactly that. mongoConnect is my main. But when I call mongoConnect, code continues, does not await

Comment: But `mongoConnect` is not your `main` as it is too small to be your entire program. mongoConnect does not even make database queries

Answer (score 2):

> I must call with await, but await is only permitted inside async functions

That's correct. So do just that:

```
async function main () {
    await mongoConnect(config.mongoUrl);

    // rest of your code...
}

main();
```

For example if this is an Express server do something like:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

async function main () {
    await mongoConnect(config.montoUrl);

    const routes = require('./my-routes');

    app.use(routes);
    app.listen(config.port);
}

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to attempt reconnect if `mongoose` fails to connect. Here is an example logic without helper lib.Props to the guy who posted this solution in a github issue for `mongoose`. [Here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5169)

```
function createConnection (dbURL, options) {
    var db = mongoose.createConnection(dbURL, options);

    db.on('error', function (err) {
        // If first connect fails because mongod is down, try again later.
        // This is only needed for first connect, not for runtime reconnects.
        // See: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5169
        if (err.message && err.message.match(/failed to connect to server .* on first connect/)) {
            console.log(new Date(), String(err));

            // Wait for a bit, then try to connect again
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log("Retrying first connect...");
                db.openUri(dbURL).catch(() => {});
                // Why the empty catch?
                // Well, errors thrown by db.open() will also be passed to .on('error'),
                // so we can handle them there, no need to log anything in the catch here.
                // But we still need this empty catch to avoid unhandled rejections.
            }, 20 * 1000);
        } else {
            // Some other error occurred.  Log it.
            console.error(new Date(), String(err));
        }
    });

    db.once('open', function () {
        console.log("Connection to db established.");
    });

    return db;
}

// Use it like
var db = createConnection('mongodb://...', options);
```

and with a lib `promise-retry`

```
const promiseRetry = require('promise-retry')

const options = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  reconnectTries: 60,
  reconnectInterval: 1000,
  poolSize: 10,
  bufferMaxEntries: 0 // If not connected, return errors immediately rather than waiting for reconnect
}

const promiseRetryOptions = {
  retries: options.reconnectTries,
  factor: 2,
  minTimeout: options.reconnectInterval,
  maxTimeout: 5000
}

const connect = () => {
  return promiseRetry((retry, number) => {
    logger.info(`MongoClient connecting to ${url} - retry number: ${number}`)
    return MongoClient.connect(url, options).catch(retry)
  }, promiseRetryOptions)
}

module.exports = { connect }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in this [article](https://medium.com/@patarkf/synchronize-your-asynchronous-code-using-javascripts-async-await-5f3fa5b1366d)

I beleive what you need is to promise your call of mongoConnect(config.mongoUrl),
than await promises until it is called back.

```
async function getConcurrently() { 
    let promises = []; 
    promises.push(mongoConnect(config.mongoUrl))
    // promises.push(getUsers()); 
    // promises.push(getCategories()); 
    // promises.push(getProducts());

    let mongo = await Promise.all(promises);
    //let [users, categories, products] = await Promise.all(promises); 
}
```

Please Note this warning in the article:

> As the first example, first we create an array of Promises (each  one of the get functions are a Promise). Then, we execute all of  them concurrently and simultaneously, awaiting for all of them to  finish (await Promise.all). Finally, we assign the results to the  respective variables users, categories and products. Despite the  fact that it works, it’s important to say that using  Promises.all() for everything is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that for some reason you have incoming events meanwhile you are attempting to connect to mongo. My approach would be preventing any incoming events (such as starting the server and setting listeners) before connection to mongo. If it's not possible, one way to do it is to use a self-invoking function.

```js
//Mongo
async function mongoConnect(mongoDB) {
    var mongoConnectionSuccessful = false;
    LOG("Connecting to mongodb at " + mongoDB + "...");
    while (!mongoConnectionSuccessful) {
        try {
            await mongoose.connect(mongoDB, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
            LOG("connected!");
            mongoConnectionSuccessful = true;
            mongoose.connection.on('error', ()=>LOG('MongoDB connection error:'));
            return;
        } catch (error) {
            LOG(error);
        }
        await utils.sleep(500);
    }
}

(async function() {
  // do stuff
  await mongoConnect(config.mongoUrl);
  // do other stuff
})();
```